# how to look at default configuration used for connecting to DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Since SpringBoot is opinionated, it connects to my Oracle DB using configuration that I didn't have to do. Now, I want to see these config values, how can I do that?

I tried the "env" and "info" actuator endpoints, but they didn't have any information on this

TIA

Comment: did you check whether below actuator endpoint work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app if you already exposed all actuator endpoints or specific configprops endpoint, you can use "configprops".

```
<host>/actuator/configprops
```

Comment: Sorry for that. Now I edited my answer and I checked  whether it work in my  machine too. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the jdbc connection url is there any configuration you specificly wanted to see? perhaps you can try to look at the logging information but it will show a lot more than just configuration values, but if you try to find list of configuration that Spring Boot set here is the reference [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html)